# Categorize recyclerview items per tab

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to group the items into tab items according to their day. For example, "Monday" tab item will only have items for Monday, while items for Wednesday will be only shown in Wednesday tab item. How can I do that? I only want to use 1 fragment to make it dynamic.

Sectioned RecyclerView items according to day

[image]

Items in database

[image: Items in database]

Here's my code for retrieving the schedules according to day.

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference =
            firebaseDatabase.getReference(FACULTY)
                    .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid());
    databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
    Query query = databaseReference.child(CONSULTATION_SCHEDULES);
    query.keepSynced(true);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                List<Schedule> schedules = new ArrayList<>();
//              list.clear();

                List<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : snapshots) {
                    Log.d("key1", snapshot.getKey());

                    days.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }

                for (String day : days) {
                    Query scheduleSortReference = ((DatabaseReference) query).child(day); //.orderByChild("day").equalTo(snapshot.getKey())
                    scheduleSortReference.keepSynced(true);
                    scheduleSortReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            Iterable<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshots) {
                                Schedule schedule = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot1.getValue(Schedule.class)).withId(Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot1.getKey()));
                                Date schedStart = new Date(Long.parseLong(schedule.getTimeStart())); //*1000
                                Date schedEnd = new Date(Long.parseLong(schedule.getTimeEnd())); //*1000

                                DateTime containedStartTime = new DateTime(schedStart);
                                DateTime containedEndTime = new DateTime(schedEnd);

                                Interval interval = new Interval(containedStartTime, containedEndTime);
                                List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
                                intervals.add(interval);
                                Collections.sort(intervals, new IntervalStartComparator());
                                Log.d("intervals sorted list?", String.valueOf(intervals) + "\n");

                                schedules.add(schedule);
                            }

                            LinkedHashMap<String, Set<Schedule>> groupedHashMap = groupScheduleDataIntoHashMap(schedules);
                            List<ListItem> consolidatedList = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (String date : groupedHashMap.keySet()) {
                                Log.d("dates", date);
                                DateItem dateItem = new DateItem();
                                dateItem.setDate(date);
                                dateItem.setDay(dayFormat.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(date))));
                                consolidatedList.add(dateItem);
                                for (Schedule schedule : Objects.requireNonNull(groupedHashMap.get(date))) {
                                    GeneralItem generalItem = new GeneralItem();
                                    generalItem.setSchedule(schedule);
                                    consolidatedList.add(generalItem);
                                }
                            }

                            listener.onFindingScheduleSuccess(consolidatedList);
//                          listener.onFindingScheduleSuccess(schedules);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            listener.onFindingScheduleFailure(databaseError.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                }

            } else {
                listener.onFindingScheduleFailure("You haven't created a schedule yet. Click the image above to start.\n\nYou may also ask your Department Secretary to arrange your Consultation Schedules.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            listener.onFindingScheduleFailure(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

This is my code for adding pages.

```
@Override
public void getPages(ConsultationDaysListener daysListener) {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dayReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(FACULTY).child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).child(CONSULTATION_SCHEDULES);
    dayReference.keepSynced(true);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager());
    List<String> dayKeys = new ArrayList<>();

    dayReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    dayKeys.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }
                for (int i = 0, dayKeysSize = dayKeys.size(); i < dayKeysSize; i++) {
                    String day = dayKeys.get(i);
                    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ConsultationScheduleFragment(), day);
                    viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                daysListener.onPageSuccess(viewPagerAdapter, dayKeys.size());
            }
            else {
                viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ConsultationScheduleFragment(), "Schedules");
                viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                daysListener.onPageFailure(viewPagerAdapter, 1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ConsultationScheduleFragment(), "Schedules");
            viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            daysListener.onPageFailure(viewPagerAdapter, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the method inside ConsultationScheduleFragment for displaying the schedules according to day. (Displaying the header which is Monday, and the item below the header)

```
@Override
public void setSchedules(List<ListItem> schedules) {
    emptySchedImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    emptySchedText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ScheduleGroupAdapter adapter = new ScheduleGroupAdapter(getActivity(), schedules);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    floatingActionButton.show();
}
```

This is what happens after applying the code above. Switching tabs from one another shows the same data.

[image: Repeating data through tab items]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to solve my problem this way:

I created differently-named fragments from monday to sunday

```
private ConsultationScheduleFragment monday = new ConsultationScheduleFragment();
private ConsultationScheduleFragment tuesday = new ConsultationScheduleFragment();
private ConsultationScheduleFragment wednesday = new ConsultationScheduleFragment();
private ConsultationScheduleFragment thursday = new ConsultationScheduleFragment();
private ConsultationScheduleFragment friday = new ConsultationScheduleFragment();
private ConsultationScheduleFragment saturday = new ConsultationScheduleFragment();
private ConsultationScheduleFragment sunday = new ConsultationScheduleFragment();
```

In my getPages method, for properly-named titles according to weekday, I used 2 sets of for-loops and a comparator to make it like this

[image]

String Comparator

```
Comparator<String> dateComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date d1 = format.parse(s1);
            Date d2 = format.parse(s2);
            if(d1.equals(d2)){
                return s1.substring(s1.indexOf(" ") + 1).compareTo(s2.substring(s2.indexOf(" ") + 1));
            }else{
                Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal1.setTime(d1);
                cal2.setTime(d2);
                return cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            }
        }catch(ParseException pe){
            throw new RuntimeException(pe);
        }
    }
};
```

I also used putString bundles to add them exact per weekday

```
Bundle mondayBundle = new Bundle();
Bundle tuesdayBundle = new Bundle();
Bundle wednesdayBundle = new Bundle();
Bundle thursdayBundle = new Bundle();
Bundle fridayBundle = new Bundle();
Bundle saturdayBundle = new Bundle();
Bundle sundayBundle = new Bundle();
```

This is where the processing goes

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     dayKeys.add(snapshot.getKey());
}
List<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0, dayKeysSize = dayKeys.size(); i < dayKeysSize; i++) {
     String day = dayKeys.get(i);
     days.add(day);
     Collections.sort(days, dateComparator);
}
for (String sortedDay : days) {
     if ("Monday".equals(sortedDay)) {
         mondayBundle.putString(SCHEDULE_DAY, "Monday");
         monday.setArguments(mondayBundle);
         viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(monday, "Monday");
         viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
     if ("Tuesday".equals(sortedDay)) {
         tuesdayBundle.putString(SCHEDULE_DAY, "Tuesday");
         tuesday.setArguments(tuesdayBundle);
         viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(tuesday, "Tuesday");
         viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
     if ("Wednesday".equals(sortedDay)) {
         wednesdayBundle.putString(SCHEDULE_DAY, "Wednesday");
         wednesday.setArguments(wednesdayBundle);
         viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(wednesday, "Wednesday");
         viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
     if ("Thursday".equals(sortedDay)) {
         thursdayBundle.putString(SCHEDULE_DAY, "Thursday");
         thursday.setArguments(thursdayBundle);
         viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(thursday, "Thursday");
         viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
     if ("Friday".equals(sortedDay)) {
         fridayBundle.putString(SCHEDULE_DAY, "Friday");
         friday.setArguments(fridayBundle);
         viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(friday, "Friday");
         viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
     if ("Saturday".equals(sortedDay)) {
         saturdayBundle.putString(SCHEDULE_DAY, "Saturday");
         saturday.setArguments(saturdayBundle);
         viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(saturday, "Saturday");
         viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
     if ("Sunday".equals(sortedDay)) {
         sundayBundle.putString(SCHEDULE_DAY, "Sunday");
         sunday.setArguments(sundayBundle);
         viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(sunday, "Sunday");
         viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
}
```

After the processing above, I called the arguments in my target fragment

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    presenter.onStart();

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    String day = Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).getString(SCHEDULE_DAY);
    presenter.requestScheduleAccordingToDay(day);
}
```

It finally worked! Yaaaay

Answer (score 0):

Using RecyclerView with multiple view holders, you can achieve that.
Here is one link that will give you a fair idea.
http://www.digitstory.com/recyclerview-multiple-viewholders/

Comment: I'm a bit confused with that because I was able to achieve it that way. But what I wanted is to group things into tab items.

Comment: I didn't get you completely, I think, you are looking for ExpandableRecyclerView or ExpandableListView. Please search for it.

Comment: I need some clarification. do you want to show Monday & Wednesday schedule under Monday tab?

Comment: I only want to show Monday schedule under Monday tab

Comment: did you check the concept of ViewPager? don't you think ViewPager and RecyclerView combination will solve the problem?

Comment: I haven't tried that. Just in case, how should I do that?

Comment: It's broad topic and implementation can't be done in short. Here is the link for ViewPage example. https://guides.codepath.com/android/viewpager-with-fragmentpageradapter, https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/viewpager

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `RecyclerView` from the fragments' `onResume()` call so that whole `RecyclerView` initializes for every tab chosen like - Monday/Wednesday.

Comment: could you give me a sample to that?

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing in ConsultationScheduleFragment() class? I'm saying that you can generate your recyclerview in onResume() method of this fragment class.

Comment: I updated my post. Please look at the code before the last image showing tab item with data displayed